# Why does using ProcessPoolExecutor only yield a 2x speed-up on an 8-core machine?

Tags: python, concurrent.futures, process-pool

I'm trying to leverage `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` to speed up CPU-bound work in Python, and I'm seeing less than 2x speed-up in execution time improvement running on a machine with 8 cores (4 cores and HyperThreading). I'm struggling to understand why.

I have the following script:

```py
import asyncio
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

CALCULATION_COUNT = 1000000

def calculate(size: int):
    # Meaningless work to keep the CPU occupied
    n = 2
    for i in range(1, size):
        n *= (i % 4) + 1
        n /= (i % 4) + 1

    return 2


# Sequential version

def run_calculations():
    return calculate(CALCULATION_COUNT)


# Parallel version

def _chunks(chunk_size):
    for _ in range(0, CALCULATION_COUNT, chunk_size):
        yield None

async def run_calculations_mp():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    tasks = []
    chunk_size = CALCULATION_COUNT // 8
    with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        for _ in _chunks(chunk_size):
            tasks.append(loop.run_in_executor(executor, calculate, chunk_size))

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

and the following code for benchmarking the functions in that script using the pytest plugin pytest_benchmark:

```py
import asyncio

from my_module import *

def test_benchmark_sequential(benchmark):
    benchmark(run_calculations)

def test_benchmark_parallel(benchmark):
    def run_sync():
        asyncio.run(run_calculations_mp())
    benchmark(run_sync)
```

I run my benchmark like this:

```bash
$ pytest \
    --benchmark-max-time=20 \
    --benchmark-warmup=on \
    --benchmark-warmup-iterations=20
```

**Expectation**

I'd expect the `run_calculations_mp` function to finish significantly faster than the `run_calculations` function. I'm running on an Intel Core i7-8565U with 4 cores and HyperThreading for a total of 8 cores. I would expect the parallelized version to have a theoretical upper bound to its speed-up of 8x; less when factoring in the overhead of spinning up sub-processes.

**Reality**

When benchmarking the two functions against one another using pytest-benchmark, I get a **1.77x** speed-up.

**Questions**

I'm confused as to why I'm only seeing a <2x speed-up in this completely contrived example. I'm not doing any I/O work; I'm not allocating a lot of memory. I don't believe I'm serializing and sending a lot of information back and forth between my worker processes from looking at the program, which might otherwise have constituted a bottleneck. Any pointers as to why this speed-up isn't significantly bigger would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

**Things I've tried**

- Using `multiprocessing.Pool` instead of `asyncio` and `ProcessPoolExecutor`, but I still only get a speed-up of about 1.72x.

[**Here's a link**](https://i.imgur.com/SfpA55Z.png) to the results of my benchmark.

Comment: Is your size high enough to "pay back" the cost to spin up the workers? (How does increasing `CALCULATION_COUNT` make this scale?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for the suggestion, and good point – I went back and increased `CALCULATION_COUNT` by 100 times (to 100M), and now, my benchmarks show x2.20 instead of x1.72. https://i.imgur.com/vTMKVQL.png

Still, for a 100x increase in size, I'm surprised the speed-up's not greater than this. I tried decreasing the number of subprocesses that are spun up to 4 (by setting `chunk_size = CALCULATION_COUNT // 4`), but that yields a speed-up of only x1.6.

Comment: You shouldn't be running a ThreadPoolExecutor w/ an event loop, at least in most cases - if you know what you're doing, fine. This isn't a fix for performance, but make run_calculations_mp a function, and remove all async from your code. Instead, in the `with` block, use `executor.submit(calculate, chunk_size)`. 

Anyways, for me on py3.11 - parallel is slower every time. Premature optimization comes to mind and parallelism is like the last thing to do too, you should at least try to use a C library like numpy first, or port to another more performant language when needed. (done prototyping)

Comment: @GRAYgoose124 Hey, thank you for your input. This example is actually a *very* simplified version of another program I'm writing in which I'm downloading a set of files, deserializing their contents, mapping to Python objects, and reducing to an array. After benchmarking my code, I found out I was CPU-bound (mapping the objects took the longest by far), so I figured I'd optimize that part using `ProcessPoolExecutor`. Thanks for suggesting numpy – there may be a way to make it work for me without changing my library's interface too much.

Comment: Well keep up the good work! I'm sure numpy will be useful to you inevitably, it's a powerful library.